# How to use the RolePermissionValueProvider

Tags: abp, role-base-authorization

How to use the RolePermissionValueProvider in the MenuContributor context.Menu.AddItem and extension .RequirePermissions ?
The objective is to add a menu item depending of the role of the user (or one role in the multiple roles of the user).

Edit :

```
context.Menu.AddItem(new ApplicationMenuItem("Name", "DisplayName").RequireAuthenticated());
```

works : add the MenuItem if the current ser is authenticated.

I would like to use

```
context.Menu.AddItem(new ApplicationMenuItem("Name", "DisplayName").RequirePermissions("PermisionName or other ?");
```

like explained here : https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization#advanced-topics

The only exemple provided is to extend the PermissionProvider, not to use the already made RolePermissionValueProvider.

Answer (score 0):

`MenuConfigurationContext` has a property named **ServiceProvider** and `context.ServiceProvider` can be used to resolve any service dependency.

> https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Navigation-Menu#resolving-dependencies

To check the current user is in a role or not, you can get the `ICurrentUser`instance and use its [`IsInRole`](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Security/Volo/Abp/Users/CurrentUser.cs#L58-L61) method. This method simply returns true or false by checking the current user's claim values.

```cs
public virtual Task ConfigureMenuAsync(MenuConfigurationContext context)
{
    //...

    var roleName = "<role-name>";

    //check if the current user is in role
    if (!context.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUser>().IsInRole(roleName)) 
    {
       //add the menu item ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. It also helps me, I was wondering how to access to the current user in some classes. I’ve updated my questions for the RequirePermissions. Many thanks